# How to enable mouse wheel scrolling in GNU screen?

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

In my GNOME Terminal, I can use my mouse wheel to scroll up and down. 
But as soon as I start `screen` in my terminal, 'mouse wheel' does not work.

How can I get my mouse wheel to work in screen?

Answer (score 4):

I've you tried to add the following line to your ~/.screenrc ?

```
    termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs ti@:te=\E[2J
```

It should solve the problem.

Comment: In addition to this, ensure you have `export TERM=xterm` set up. The $TERM variable to match this `termcapinfo` configuration.